# Horizontal scrolling text in Android

Tags: android, text, textview, horizontal-scrolling

I've been looking around for quite some time now, and I can't get a straight answer for my question.

It's quite simple: How can I get a nice scrolling text just like the long app names in the Market when you select an application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've figured it out by myself.

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Ah, your TextView is in a ListView ! Btw, don't work with focusableInTouchMode until you fully understand it and mark the question as answered.

Comment: No, it's in a `RelativeLayout` that is used as a custom title... I can't mark it as answered until tomorrow because of my lack of reputation

Answer (score 8):

Make a translate animation in your anim folder like:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="12000"
    android:fromXDelta="100"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-100" />
```

And then to your textview like:

```
yourtextview.startAnimation((Animation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Context,R.anim.youranim_xml));
```

Hope this might help you.

**Edit:**

Try this:

```
<TextView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:lines="1"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:padding="4dp"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text" />
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot.

Comment: Animation is working but how to remove ... from the end of the textview and increase the size of textview to its content

Comment: @Hemant `yourtextview.clearAnimation()` will stop the animation. You can do textview ui staffs after that.

Comment: @IronBlossom Man .actually animation is clipping rest of the text its like this `Today's news this that die injured ...`
the rest of the text is clipped 
I want to increase the size of TextView cause animation is animating just this much part not the whole text

Comment: @Hemant Set your textview ellipsize to `none` and `layout_width=wrap_content`

Comment: @IronBlossom I have tried this but still size remains same. it is clipping the   textview width .Also i am using singleline="true"

Comment: hey its Done i have Put my Text View in `HorizontalScrollView`. how to increase the speed of animation'

Answer (score 6):

the decision which works for me:

```
textView.setSelected(true); 
textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
textView.setSingleLine(true);
```

without focusable's parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Comment: I've tried that, and it doesn't work...  

`<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView02" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:singleLine="true" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="#fff"></TextView>`

Comment: I have also tried that and it doesn't work for me too `<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Random long line of text to check scroll functionality... bla bla bla" />`

Comment: I have my textview inside LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a normal TextView with the following config:

   ```
   android:text="your text here"
   android:id="@+id/MarqueeText"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
   ```

The problem with this is that you cannot adjust the speed of the scrolling text.

2. Enclose a `TextView` within a `ScrollView`:

```html
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Text here" >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>
```

3. Create custom class and follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8971920/4269615)