# I want to display a scrolling text in Android

Tags: android

I want to display a scrolling text in Android just like a marquee tag functionality in HTML. How can i display like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `android:ellipsize="marquee"` to your TextView xml.

Answer (score 0):

A search would reveal the answer:

[Horizontal scrolling text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862409/horizontal-scrolling-text-in-android)