# How to scroll text Horizontally in textview in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horizontal scrolling text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862409/horizontal-scrolling-text-in-android)

```
<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/dtitle"
  android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
  android:text="Title"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
 />
```

This is my code in xml file

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like a [marquee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862409/horizontal-scrolling-text-in-android)?