# How to settext on singleline TextView which length is over screen width

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, textview

I have a TextView and want to show it with animation.

but when I set a text over screen width, it will be cut

How can I fix it.

[image]

[Video Text is cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R33M7.jpg)

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="startmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmend"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

How I animate it

```
val bounds = Rect()
viewBinding.textView.paint.getTextBounds(
    viewBinding.textView.text.toString(),
    0,
    viewBinding.textView.text.length, bounds)

viewBinding.textView
           .animate()
           .setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
           .x((screenWidth - bounds.width()).toFloat())
           .duration = 5000
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862409/horizontal-scrolling-text-in-android   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472362/android-automatic-horizontally-scrolling-textview

Comment: @Manohar Thanks. But i don't want to use `Marquee` because it is diffcult to customize animation

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:lines="1" // this
        android:text="startmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmend"
```

As you can see on your xml code, it provide max lines is 1, it will cut all view outside the scope of element view, [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setLines(int)). So for the solution you can make it inside horizontal scrollview then animate the scrollview for auto scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem myself

Calculate the Text width and set the TextView width programmtically

```
    val defaultPadding = 50
    val bounds = Rect()
    val text = viewBinding.textView.text.toString()
    viewBinding.textView.paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, bounds)
    textView.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
        bounds.width() + defaultPadding, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    ConstraintSet().apply {
        clone(viewBinding.rootLayout)
        connect(R.id.textView, ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.rootLayout, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0)
        connect(R.id.textView, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.rootLayout, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0)
        connect(R.id.textView, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.rootLayout, ConstraintSet.TOP, 350)
        applyTo(viewBinding.rootLayout)
    }
    viewBinding.textView
               .animate()
               .setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
               .x((screenWidth - bounds.width()-defaultPadding).toFloat())
               .duration = 5000
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUvFL.jpg)